# SubSonic 3 Repository - SQLite In-Memory

Tags: sqlite, subsonic, subsonic3, in-memory-database

Before I invest the time in modifying the SubSonic 3 source, I figured I ask to see if I'm missing something simple.

Is it possible to use the SubSonic 3 Repository with migrations on a SQLite In-Memory database? I couldn't find a way to force the DbDataProvider to keep the connection open so the In-Memory SQLite database doesn't vanish when the connection get's closed.

The unit test with the connection string I was trying is...

```
public class SQLite_InMemory_SimpleRepositoryTests
{
    public class Job
    {
        public Guid JobId { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SQLite_InMemory_SimpleRepo_CanStayOpen()
    {
        IDataProvider provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;", "System.Data.SQLite");
        IRepository repository = new SimpleRepository(provider, SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            var job = new Job {JobId = Guid.NewGuid(), JobName = "Job_"+i};
            repository.Add(job);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting the "Shared Connection" on the IDataProvider, but the connection still seemed to close.

If not, I'll update the SubSonic source, and submit the changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting - no there's no way that I can think of to do this other than maybe creating a static IDataProvider but even then we close off the connection for doing things like executing scalar's etc.

I spose you could create such a thing by implementing the IDataProvider then setting things up as you need - all the execution goes through it. But this is making me wonder if we explicitly shut things down in the calling code - which would be bad design on my part... hmmm.\

Would love to have this feature...

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the info. I did a trace on the execution and it's calling Close and Dispose in a few places. I was going to implement an extension method on the IDataProvider called bool IsSqlLiteMemoryDb() that would check the connection type and :memory: in the connection string and override the disposes/closes. Where should a post the code?

Comment: Also, just to note, I was able to get the test to pass, but 'hackishly'. I'm going to refactor the code, and post it. Just let me know where. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll branch and post.